# Counter to Keep Track of Macro Usage

Tags: excel, vba

I need a counter that keeps track of each time the macro has been ran in excel.  I have been able to get it to work in an individual cell no problem.  My issue is that I need that cell to hold the value and not be overwritten.  So I need a counter that starts in A1 with 1, then when ran again, B1 goes to 2, then when ran again, C1 goes to 3.

From there, I need to be able to have the macro call back to the cell that was just recently updated as I will have a table copy that number in one of its columns.

So each time this macro is ran, a table is being generated and the first column needs to equal the number that was just generated using the counter.

```
Sub GenerateSupplyChain()

'Range("A18").Value = Range("A18").Value + 1     Works, but in same cell, need to have it count downwards

Dim MySheet As String, ws As Worksheet
MySheet = Sheets("Instructions").Range("T1").Value
Set ws = Sheets(MySheet)
    
    Const COL_KEY = "O" ' used to determine the last row
    Const FIRST_ROW = 5
    Const HEADER_RNG = "D2:AS2" ' source of header
    Const BASE_SHT = "Base Data"
    Dim i As Variant
    i = InputBox("How many DFSP's in this Supply Chain?", "Enter Quantity")
    If Not IsNumeric(i) Then
        MsgBox "Please input a number.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If i < 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Set oSht = Sheets(MySheet)
    LastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, COL_KEY).End(xlUp).Row
    With oSht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY)
        If Len(.Value) > 0 Or (Not .ListObject Is Nothing) Then
            LastRow = LastRow + 2
        End If
        If LastRow < FIRST_ROW Then LastRow = FIRST_ROW
    End With
    Dim tabRng As Range, headerRng As Range, objtable As ListObject
    Set headerRng = Sheets("BASE Data").Range(HEADER_RNG)
    Set tabRng = oSht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY).Resize(i + 1, headerRng.Columns.Count)
    Set objtable = Worksheets(MySheet).ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tabRng, , xlYes)
    objtable.HeaderRowRange.Value = headerRng.Value
    objtable.ShowTotals = True
    objtable.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
    
  ' objtable.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Formula = _   Doesnt work
       ' "=A18"
    'objtable.DataBodyRange(1, 1).FillDown (Offset - 1)     doestn work
    
   ' Set rngFormula = tblrng.Offset(1, LastRow - 1).Resize(rowData - 1, 1)  doesnt work
    'rngFormula.FillDown

    
    objtable.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 6).Formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objtable.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!A:N,3,FALSE)"
        objtable.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 7).Formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objtable.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!A:N,3,FALSE)"
        objtable.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 8).Formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objtable.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!A:N,3,FALSE)"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a counter that goes along the columns in row 1 and adds 1 to that value every time the macro is run is relatively simple. You could even remove the first part of the If statement if you plan to just always carry a 1 in the first column.

```vb
Sub GenerateSupplyChain()
    Dim counterSheet As Worksheet
    Set counterSheet = Sheets("CounterSheet")
    
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = counterSheet.Cells(1, counterSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    If lastColumn = 1 And IsEmpty(counterSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
        counterSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
    Else
        counterSheet.Cells(1, lastColumn + 1).Value = counterSheet.Cells(1, lastColumn).Value + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is a good tutorial on finding ranges/columns in excel: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/

You can then grab the currentCounterValue and place it wherever needed.

```vb
    Dim currentCounterValue As Long
    currentCounterValue = counterSheet.Cells(1, lastColumn).Value
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I put CurrentCounterValue in this line of code?          objTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Formula = _
    "=CurrentCounterValue"

Comment: @RyanDataGuy You don't use `.Formula` here, use `.Value`.
`objtable.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = currentCounterValue`

Comment: Awwww, thanks!  Last thing, how would I get that to be in the entire column within the List Object.  Currently its just in top row, not all rows

Comment: You can count all rows in your objtable, and set all rows within the first column value as your current counter value.

With objtable
    rowCount = .ListRows.Count
        If rowCount > 0 Then
        .DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Value = currentCounterValue
    End If
End With